# Вопрос - ответ через бота в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на инлайновую кнопку
Я мог ответить пользователю через бота ?

```
def answer(message):
chat_id = message.from_user.id
x = 11111111
db.users_collection.find_one_and_update({"chat_id":chat_id},{"$set":{"MFUs":message.text}})
bot.send_message(x,f'Сообщение от : {message.from_user.first_name} \nТекст сообщения : ' + message.text,
reply_markup=markups.markup)
text = ' Ваш вопрос принят'
bot.send_message(chat_id,text)
```